# How to serialize UIMA CAS combined with Java Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, cas, uima

I have these classes:

```
class DocumentObj implements Serializable {
    ...
    List<SentenceObj> sentenceObjs;
    JCas docJcas;
}
class SentenceObj implements Serializable {
    ...
    annotation.Sentence sentenceAnnotation;
}
```

I would like to dump each DocumentObj as a file on disk, using the default Java serialization. Later they would also be deserialized back into the Java objects. I understand I would need some special treatment for the JCases and the Sentence Annotations as they are not serializable (now I get `NotSerializableException`). Hopefully the treatment could be as minimal as possible.

How do you suggest to do this, regarding serialization of JCas and combining it with Java serialization?

I am working on Windows, with Java 1.6 and UIMA 2.4.0. I am using the same type system and the same 3 views for all JCases and annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use default Java serialization. Use instead the `org.apache.uima.cas.impl.Serialization` utilities, or even better the [BinaryCasWriter](https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-core/releases/1.8.0/apidocs/de/tudarmstadt/ukp/dkpro/core/io/bincas/BinaryCasWriter.html) from DK-pro.